# Import android project in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an android project which I created in eclipse. Is it possible to import it in Unity for  further development. If yes, please let me know the steps

Answer (score 0):

No. Unity is only for developing Unity projects.

You can create external libraries (in Eclipse) which can be called from within Unity, but you cannot edit or develop them from within Unity.

Answer (score 0):

you can create plugin for communicate with Unity. C# can call java method. You can read this link for create a plugin: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html